# How do I turn off the distortion effect and keep the song playing? Tone.js

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble turning off the distortion effect and keeping the song playing. My current code turns off the distortion effect, but also turns off the song.

Here's my code:

```
  //Play effect

   if(h < 50)
   {
     player.connect(distorty);
   }



//Stop Effect
  if(i < 50)
  {
    player.dispose(distorty);
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **disconnect()**
 function to disconnect the distortion from the source. However, this will disconnect **all** the effects (I might be wrong here but I think that is what would happen). If that doesn't work or if you want to turn off only one effect you can try to bypass the effect by turning its **wet** signal down to 0.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know which method worked for you, and did it create a problem when multiple effects were applied?